# Fourier transform of $\cos(\sqrt{a^2 - x^2})$ - a surface optics related problem

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This Fourier transform of $\cos(\sqrt{a^2 - x^2})$ has come up in relation to a physics problem.  Searching through Gradshteyn and Rhyzik didn't turn anything up, and trying a number of changes of variable didn't produce anything obvious.

One idea was to make an approximation in which one restricts the range of integration from -a to a, as the contribution outside of this range would be relatively small due to the damping effect of the cosine of an imaginary argument.  Then a change of variables with $x = a\sin\phi$
would hopefully lead to a doable integration. This is also not an obvious one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the graph for your function, it very much looks like a degree four polynomial. Doing a Taylor expansion up to order four shows a very close resemblance. Mathematica does know how to Fourier transform polynomials, but it involves the delta-function and its derivatives. There is probably a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  I expect the result, if there is an analytic one, would relate to Bessel functions, as making the transform x=asinϕ leads to a factor in the integrand that looks like $\cos(a\cos\phi + b\sin\phi)$

Comment: Wouldn't that substitution lead to your function being just $\cos(a\cos(\phi))$?

Comment: Yes, for the function, but I used the substitution in the actual Fourier transform integral, so overall it is a little more complicated.